# How is the best way to share videos on facebook associated to a website

Tags: facebook

I am trying to share videos on facebook page wall from my website.

What I want to achieve is that, when someone clicks on the video, should be a redirect to my site to watch the video.

I see videos playing silently when I scroll through News Feed. And when I click on such videos, I am taken to the website url that published the video.

How can I achieve this with my videos?

I don't mind uploading the videos directly on facebook, as long as onclick will redirect to my own website.

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the video and see "properties". Highlight the link by right clicking and select Copy. Go to your source editor (Wordpad,Facebook) and click paste or manually type it in your website builder or page builder. Use the

```
<p> <a href="http://yoursite.com/video link.mpg">Title of Movie Here</a>
```

use the end `</p>` tag `</p>` to end your sentence.

Comment: I don't understand what u are trying to say? U mean should I edit the video details before uploading into facebook? And where do I add the url? Promotion Url or author url?